# How to filter arrays using another array value in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this table with a select option in each row,
and according to 'dataType' in each row the value of select option will change.

Table Array:

```
{
'name':'Name',
'count': 22,
'dataType':'numerical'
}
{
'name':'Name',
'count': 44,
'dataType':'string'
}
]
```

select option array :

```
{
'numerical':['1', '2', '3'],
'string':['a', 'b', 'c'],
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How can i filter out the options according to the dataTypes ?

Answer (score 1):

it's equal in a table or in a div (unless you use mat-table or another library to show a table)

```
<div *ngFor="let data of tableArray">
<!--here data is each element of the array-->
  {{data.Name}} <!--give you the value of "data.Name"-->
  {{data.dataType}} <!--give you the value of "data.dataType"-->
  {{option[data.dataType] |json}} <!--give you the array option["numerical"]
                                      or the array option["string"]
  <select>
    <option *ngFor="let value of option[data.dataType]" [value]="value">
       {{value}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**But** (always there are a but) remember use [(ngModel)] or use ReaciveForms if you want to "store" the values selected in variables of the .ts. It's impossible know what are you try to do with your brief explain of the question